# Time series with multiple subjects and multiple variables in R

Tags: r, time-series, machine-learning, forecasting, panel-data

I'm having trouble finding a time series technique to deal with a data set I am working on. It contains multiple subjects and multiple variables, not all of which will likely be part of the time series. It looks something like this:

```
Subject  Date      T1  T2  V1  V2  V3
A        1/1/2012  1   5   9   13  17
A        2/1/2012  2   6   10  14  18
...
B        1/1/2012  3   7   11  15  19
B        2/1/2012  4   8   12  16  20
...
```

Where T1, T2 are likely time series, and V1, V2, and V3 are likely not. I'm sure that this distinction is probably unnecessary, since techniques like Box-Jenkins should detect autoregression in any variable.

Ultimately, I want to be able to do forecasting on other subjects that were probably not used to build this model.

If you know of any R package(s) that can take this on, please let me know. Some example code would also be greatly appreciated. Thank you for any insight you can provide.

Edit: I am looking into dynamic linear regression using the `dynlm` package, but am having trouble coding it to include the dates and subjects.

Comment: Given the data table that you show, I would recommend you to look for methods for panel data rather than for time series. See this [information](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/panel-data/info) for the tag "panel data" and the questions related to it. If you find it related to your question you may add this tag and check the [Econometrics CRAN Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Econometrics.html) for R packages that are available to work with panel data.

Comment: Are you only looking for code / packages? If so, that would be off-topic here, but we could migrate this to SO.

Comment: The panel data description seems to fit perfectly. I will look into some techniques there. @gung, I'm mostly looking into techniques, though pointing me in the right direction with packages or code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever get `dynlm` working?

Answer (score 1):

The Arima function in the forecast package can fit a regression model to the data with an ARIMA model for the errors. The `order` argument specifies the orders of the ARIMA model, while the argument `xreg` defines which data object contains the observations of the predictors. E.g., if `xreg` is a matrix of predictors:

```
model = Arima(series, order = c(1,1,0), xreg = covariates)
```

To find the order of the ARIMA process, you can simply use the `auto.arima` function also found in the forecast package. It automatically locates the best-fitting ARIMA model to the data, “fit” defined by one of three possible information criteria in the `ic` argument: the AIC (given by `aic`), the AICc (`aicc`), or the BIC (`bic`). E.g.,

```
model = auto.arima(series, ic = “aic”)
```

I think you may find [this](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/) page really helpful, especially the section about R.

Comment: I'm not sure if the above link is working: http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/

Comment: Does this support multiple subjects?