# How to analyze time series with multiple readings per unit time

Tags: time-series, seasonality

I have data as follows:

```
day_number          readings
1                       4,5,6
2                       4,7
3                       5,6,4,3
4                       3,5,6
5                       5,6,4,3,2
....
```

Multiple values of readings come from different subjects seen on the same day. No subject is repeated in the data. Hence 3 subjects were seen on day1, another 2 on day 2, further 4 on day 4, etc. These go on for about 4 years.

I want to determine if there is a seasonal effect on readings. How can I analyze this data? Do I take mean at each time only but then I will not be taking into account the variances on different days.

I checked at other sites but here they had same readings per unit time: [Time series with multiple subjects and multiple variables in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135011/time-series-with-multiple-subjects-and-multiple-variables-in-r)
and 
[Time series with multiple subjects and multiple variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26432/time-series-with-multiple-subjects-and-multiple-variables)

Comment: One way is to create indicartor variables. You will have a constant number of binary "responses" this way. The representation is only a means to an end - the best way to handle this data ultimately depends on the type of analysis you plan to carry out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if time-series would be your best solution for analyzing these data, but before you can get ts format out of what you have here, you will need to use the `splitstackshape package` and clean up the data:

```
install.packages("splitstackshape")
library("splitstackshape")

data

day_number  readings
1          1     4,5,6
2          2       4,7
3          3   5,6,4,3
4          4     3,5,6
5          5 5,6,4,3,2

data_new <- cSplit(data, "readings", sep=",", "long")
```

Your dataset now looks like this:

```
data_new

    day_number readings
 1:          1        4
 2:          1        5
 3:          1        6
 4:          2        4
 5:          2        7
 6:          3        5
 7:          3        6
 8:          3        4
 9:          3        3
10:          4        3
11:          4        5
12:          4        6
13:          5        5
14:          5        6
15:          5        4
16:          5        3
17:          5        2
```

From here, you can add the subject ID by doing the following:

```
data_new$subject_id <- 1:nrow(data_new)

       day_number readings subject_id
 1:          1        4          1
 2:          1        5          2
 3:          1        6          3
 4:          2        4          4
 5:          2        7          5
 6:          3        5          6
 7:          3        6          7
 8:          3        4          8
 9:          3        3          9
10:          4        3         10
11:          4        5         11
12:          4        6         12
13:          5        5         13
14:          5        6         14
15:          5        4         15
16:          5        3         16
17:          5        2         17
```

I really want to recommend that you consider using panel data modeling for this, but I have not honestly thought it through (especially with the dataset being quite unbalanced). So, I can only recommend that you do some research on panel data model, as well as on the `package plm` in R.

I hope this is useful in some way.